# Haskell code - a list of lists as an argument

Tags: haskell

I´ve written the following code:

```
set :: [[Int]] -> [Int]

set [[]]    = []

set ((x:xs)) = x : set xs
```

I have as an argument a list of lists. And I try to make it to one list. In the first declaration I wanted to say that an empty list in a list should give me an empty list.
In the second, I wanted to express that I take the first element of a list and insert it to the new list and so on.

But when I compile this then I get the following message:

```
Couldnt match the expected type ´Int´ with actual type ´[Int]´
In the first argument of (:) namely 'x'
In the expression: x: set xs
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: The standard name for this function is [concat](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concat).

Answer (score 2):

`(x:xs)` has type `[[Int]]`. So `x` has type `[Int]` and `xs` has type `[[Int]]`. Now, your function is expected to give an answer of type `[Int]`, but `x : set xs` can't possibly have that type. Do you see why?

**Hint**: look at the type of the `:` operator.

Comment: i looked up the type of the :-operator. I found out that the of :-operator is a list, so it would be like [Int]. but when xs is from type [[Int]] then it doesnt work, right ?....hmmh...ok

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, here is a correct definition:

```
flatten [] = []
flatten (x:xs) = x ++ flatten xs
```

Testing:

```
> flatten [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Or just `foldr (++) []`.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov Yeah, that is the definition used by [concat](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/src/GHC-List.html#concat), the definition in my answer is based on the problematic code in the original question, so maybe it is easier for the asker to understand.